# Let A be an $n \times n$ matrix. Prove that $dim(span{I_n,A,A^2,...}) \leq n$.

Tags: linear-algebra, cayley-hamilton

> Let A be an $n \times n$ matrix. Prove that $dim(span{I_n,A,A^2,...}) \leq n$.

I am thinking about the theorem( Let T be a linear operator on a finite-dimensional vector space V, and let W denote the T-cyclic subspace of v generated by a noznero vector $v \in V$. Let k=dim(W), then ${v,T(v),T^2(v),...,T^{k-1}(v)}$ is a basis for W). I am also encouraged to think about Cayley-Hamilton theorem, but I don't see the interconnection here. Can someone point out what to do? Thanks.

Comment: Cayley Hamiltion shows that $A^n \in \operatorname{sp} \{ I, A, ..., A^{n-1} \}$.